# How can i create HTML report in JMeter using Bean shell sampler in tear down thread?

Tags: jmeter, report, performance-testing, load-testing

I want to create an HTML report automatically after running each test in JMeter, also I want to create a folder dynamically with the current timestamp as a folder name for placing the report on my local drive. So how can we do this operation using Bean Shell sampler in tear down thread group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is not very good as it violates 2 major [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html):

1. You will need a Listener in order to write down the results and using Listeners is a [performance anti-pattern](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/)
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting

So I would recommend:

1. [Run your JMeter test in non-GUI mode and generate dashboard after it](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_after_load_test)
2. Use your operating system `date` and `time` command to create the folder with the timestamp

   - Windows example:

     ```
     jmeter -f -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o results-%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%
     ```
   - Linux example:

     ```
     jmeter -f -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl -e -o results-`date +%Y-%m-%d`
     ```